# Actions on Google - The intent the app is asking permission for is not found

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Alright, this is weird, it's the second time I've gotten this and something does not seem right.

The error I get when trying to opt in for push notifications:
`MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..`

When I first created this intent, it worked, now it does not.

Here is the intent in my actions:
[image]

Here is the intent in my dialogflow:
[image]

How is it possible that my intent is not found, when it's clearly in dialogflow - and available in AoG.

My code for these permission intents:

```js
app.intent('innercircle_notification_request', (conv) => {
    console.log('innercircle_notification_request')
    conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({
        intent: 'inner_circle_notification'
    }));
});
app.intent('innercircle_notification_request_finish', (conv) => {
    if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
        const userID = conv.arguments.get('UPDATES_USER_ID');
        User.default.setUserId({
            intent: 'inner_circle_notification',
            id: userID,
            gaToken: Settings.default.accessToken
        });
        conv.close(`Ok, you will now receive messages from your inner circle.`);
    } else {
        conv.close(`Ok, I won't notify you.`);
    }
});
```

Request:

```js
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHFptFALNqLXxqWSOHQ9V9o9TOgeEkPNOU1akvPC2900EAFvalF7ANlRUiQHh1k1pvWmCo4UO0yDfQ",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2019-02-04T22:56:44Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "TOUCH",
          "query": "Send Updates"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "Send Updates",
          "textValue": "Send Updates"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

Response:

```js
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"requestinnercirclenotifications\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {},
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "inputValueData": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
            "permissions": [
              "UPDATE"
            ],
            "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
              "intent": "inner_circle_notification"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$fish",
        "$lunar-event",
        "$log-type",
        "$lure",
        "$username",
        "$weather",
        "$lure-color"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "a89ed259-dc99-4ded-9567-5bf85b1a93ee"
    },
    "delegatedRequest": {
      "delegatedRequest": "{\n  \"responseId\": \"5a1f3c7a-96cd-4ea2-91b0-04b232e916a0\",\n  \"queryResult\": {\n    \"queryText\": \"Send Updates\",\n    \"action\": \"innercircle_notification_request\",\n    \"parameters\": {\n    },\n    \"allRequiredParamsPresent\": true,\n    \"fulfillmentMessages\": [{\n      \"text\": {\n        \"text\": [\"\"]\n      }\n    }],\n    \"outputContexts\": [{\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_touch\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/requestinnercirclenotifications\",\n      \"lifespanCount\": 5\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio\"\n    }],\n    \"intent\": {\n      \"name\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/intents/a89ed259-dc99-4ded-9567-5bf85b1a93ee\",\n      \"displayName\": \"innercircle_notification_request\"\n    },\n    \"intentDetectionConfidence\": 1.0,\n    \"languageCode\": \"en-us\"\n  },\n  \"originalDetectIntentRequest\": {\n    \"source\": \"google\",\n    \"version\": \"2\",\n    \"payload\": {\n      \"isInSandbox\": true,\n      \"surface\": {\n        \"capabilities\": [{\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"\n        }]\n      },\n      \"requestType\": \"SIMULATOR\",\n      \"inputs\": [{\n        \"rawInputs\": [{\n          \"query\": \"Send Updates\",\n          \"inputType\": \"TOUCH\"\n        }],\n        \"arguments\": [{\n          \"rawText\": \"Send Updates\",\n          \"textValue\": \"Send Updates\",\n          \"name\": \"text\"\n        }],\n        \"intent\": \"actions.intent.TEXT\"\n      }],\n      \"user\": {\n        \"lastSeen\": \"2019-02-04T22:56:44Z\",\n        \"locale\": \"en-US\",\n        \"userId\": \"ABwppHFptFALNqLXxqWSOHQ9V9o9TOgeEkPNOU1akvPC2900EAFvalF7ANlRUiQHh1k1pvWmCo4UO0yDfQ\"\n      },\n      \"conversation\": {\n        \"conversationId\": \"ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\",\n        \"type\": \"ACTIVE\",\n        \"conversationToken\": \"[]\"\n      },\n      \"availableSurfaces\": [{\n        \"capabilities\": [{\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"\n        }]\n      }]\n    }\n  },\n  \"session\": \"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\"\n}"
    },
    "delegatedResponse": {
      "delegatedResponse": "{\"payload\":{\"google\":{\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"systemIntent\":{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.PERMISSION\",\"data\":{\"@type\":\"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec\",\"permissions\":[\"UPDATE\"],\"updatePermissionValueSpec\":{\"intent\":\"inner_circle_notification\"}}}}}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Debug:

```js
{
  "response": "Lake Labs isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "Eo8CS2s1Tk...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASWK...",
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=903697cd96b346e5b626c4d25a9f55fa' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZmYjA1Zjc0MjM2NmVlNGNmNGJjZjQ5Zjk4NGM0ODdlNDVjOGM4M2QiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJsYWtlbGFic3ZvaWNlIiwibmJmIjoxNTQ5MzMyNDU3LCJpYXQiOjE1NDkzMzI3NTcsImV4cCI6MTU0OTMzMjg3NywianRpIjoiOTFmMTliNjE5MGI1ZTc4NTU4NjkzNGQzZDYxNzVlMzQ2YzVlNTEwMCJ9.TmL0YGyPCrFJrnMEvGLZHiyj6dtz4m2iyJ_b1MpBj4N1kMtCW_sOzNYJ4KZAS_Sde7Y_-NfjpKFvZ9VCrnzuYU3WvZFBZ1ZUceOBEvMJ3geL8pSeLqtTOyI8C9DET55IU6aeaxyKswaa9mfOSf4wjWKLqi5TX8Nle1wCcb1jZc0H2JrHB2VMVr0Vw9gg_d_UyQXTdapMqbRLG-Weud6AZgPbH0dzgjxHJMOklG9bUdUfrqtPIWwCd3i4NTGOuIkzb2VB5Skr7NaEW5Q4IzrTeyMfhvBLElcO_AZx3-OFG_EW85Bbaw-5K5xJfAZAzGBxlJM5MPG1KLEJvHFytOfzkA'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHFptFALNqLXxqWSOHQ9V9o9TOgeEkPNOU1akvPC2900EAFvalF7ANlRUiQHh1k1pvWmCo4UO0yDfQ\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-02-04T22:56:44Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"TOUCH\",\"query\":\"Send Updates\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"Send Updates\",\"textValue\":\"Send Updates\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHFptFALNqLXxqWSOHQ9V9o9TOgeEkPNOU1akvPC2900EAFvalF7ANlRUiQHh1k1pvWmCo4UO0yDfQ\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2019-02-04T22:56:44Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"TOUCH\",\"query\":\"Send Updates\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"Send Updates\",\"textValue\":\"Send Updates\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}",
      "delegatedRequest": {
        "delegatedRequest": ""
      }
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"requestinnercirclenotifications\\\"]\",\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"expectedInputs\":[{\"inputPrompt\":{},\"possibleIntents\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.PERMISSION\",\"inputValueData\":{\"@type\":\"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec\",\"permissions\":[\"UPDATE\"],\"updatePermissionValueSpec\":{\"intent\":\"inner_circle_notification\"}}}],\"speechBiasingHints\":[\"$fish\",\"$lunar-event\",\"$log-type\",\"$lure\",\"$username\",\"$weather\",\"$lure-color\"]}],\"responseMetadata\":{\"status\":{\"message\":\"Success (200)\"},\"queryMatchInfo\":{\"queryMatched\":true,\"intent\":\"a89ed259-dc99-4ded-9567-5bf85b1a93ee\"},\"delegatedRequest\":{\"delegatedRequest\":\"{\\n  \\\"responseId\\\": \\\"5a1f3c7a-96cd-4ea2-91b0-04b232e916a0\\\",\\n  \\\"queryResult\\\": {\\n    \\\"queryText\\\": \\\"Send Updates\\\",\\n    \\\"action\\\": \\\"innercircle_notification_request\\\",\\n    \\\"parameters\\\": {\\n    },\\n    \\\"allRequiredParamsPresent\\\": true,\\n    \\\"fulfillmentMessages\\\": [{\\n      \\\"text\\\": {\\n        \\\"text\\\": [\\\"\\\"]\\n      }\\n    }],\\n    \\\"outputContexts\\\": [{\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_touch\\\"\\n    }, {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output\\\"\\n    }, {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/requestinnercirclenotifications\\\",\\n      \\\"lifespanCount\\\": 5\\n    }, {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output\\\"\\n    }, {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser\\\"\\n    }, {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio\\\"\\n    }],\\n    \\\"intent\\\": {\\n      \\\"name\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/intents/a89ed259-dc99-4ded-9567-5bf85b1a93ee\\\",\\n      \\\"displayName\\\": \\\"innercircle_notification_request\\\"\\n    },\\n    \\\"intentDetectionConfidence\\\": 1.0,\\n    \\\"languageCode\\\": \\\"en-us\\\"\\n  },\\n  \\\"originalDetectIntentRequest\\\": {\\n    \\\"source\\\": \\\"google\\\",\\n    \\\"version\\\": \\\"2\\\",\\n    \\\"payload\\\": {\\n      \\\"isInSandbox\\\": true,\\n      \\\"surface\\\": {\\n        \\\"capabilities\\\": [{\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\\\"\\n        }, {\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\\\"\\n        }, {\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\\\"\\n        }, {\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\\\"\\n        }]\\n      },\\n      \\\"requestType\\\": \\\"SIMULATOR\\\",\\n      \\\"inputs\\\": [{\\n        \\\"rawInputs\\\": [{\\n          \\\"query\\\": \\\"Send Updates\\\",\\n          \\\"inputType\\\": \\\"TOUCH\\\"\\n        }],\\n        \\\"arguments\\\": [{\\n          \\\"rawText\\\": \\\"Send Updates\\\",\\n          \\\"textValue\\\": \\\"Send Updates\\\",\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"text\\\"\\n        }],\\n        \\\"intent\\\": \\\"actions.intent.TEXT\\\"\\n      }],\\n      \\\"user\\\": {\\n        \\\"lastSeen\\\": \\\"2019-02-04T22:56:44Z\\\",\\n        \\\"locale\\\": \\\"en-US\\\",\\n        \\\"userId\\\": \\\"ABwppHFptFALNqLXxqWSOHQ9V9o9TOgeEkPNOU1akvPC2900EAFvalF7ANlRUiQHh1k1pvWmCo4UO0yDfQ\\\"\\n      },\\n      \\\"conversation\\\": {\\n        \\\"conversationId\\\": \\\"ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\\\",\\n        \\\"type\\\": \\\"ACTIVE\\\",\\n        \\\"conversationToken\\\": \\\"[]\\\"\\n      },\\n      \\\"availableSurfaces\\\": [{\\n        \\\"capabilities\\\": [{\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\\\"\\n        }, {\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\\\"\\n        }, {\\n          \\\"name\\\": \\\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\\\"\\n        }]\\n      }]\\n    }\\n  },\\n  \\\"session\\\": \\\"projects/lakelabsvoice/agent/sessions/ABwppHFkNV1WPWYYfituxrV-Lm5zUFYQXmqmzC9-iO5MdbIMl6xVkuBa1fpQa23BX9yMrsU_hvWH8rn6YQ\\\"\\n}\"},\"delegatedResponse\":{\"delegatedResponse\":\"{\\\"payload\\\":{\\\"google\\\":{\\\"expectUserResponse\\\":true,\\\"systemIntent\\\":{\\\"intent\\\":\\\"actions.intent.PERMISSION\\\",\\\"data\\\":{\\\"@type\\\":\\\"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec\\\",\\\"permissions\\\":[\\\"UPDATE\\\"],\\\"updatePermissionValueSpec\\\":{\\\"intent\\\":\\\"inner_circle_notification\\\"}}}}}}\"}}}",
      "delegatedResponse": {
        "delegatedResponse": ""
      }
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "debugInfo": "",
        "subDebugEntryList": [
          {
            "name": "MalformedResponse",
            "debugInfo": "expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..",
            "subDebugEntryList": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Lake Labs isn't responding right now. Try again soon."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": 1,
  "clientOperationList": [],
  "projectName": ""
}
```

Screen shot of simulator:
[image]

Comment: This message is appearing in the simulator? Can you update your question to include the text in the "request", "response", "debug", and "error" tabs in the simulator when you try this? Which device are you simulating when you try this? You say this only happens sometimes? Any consistency when?

Comment: Currently it happens all the time, the sequence seems to go something like this: create intent, toggle on push notifications, ask for permission to access this intent. when i ask later for access it throws an error saying it cannot find the intent

Comment: Try refreshing the simulator and try again.

Comment: I have tried refreshing, clearing cache, and running in an incognito window - the results are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an action with a draft version and an alpha version - the current draft works correctly, but the alpha version I have saved gives the same `expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..` that you are running into.

Have you turned on the "Auto-preview changes" toggle in the Integrations section of Dialogflow? Dialogflow > Integrations > Google Assistant > Scroll down:
[Auto-preview changes toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8PzC.png)

After doing that (if you haven't already), do you still get the error if you try the following?

1. Re-select the DRAFT version of your action in Simulator (click on "CHANGE VERSION" and re-select "VERSION - Draft"), then refresh the Simulator
2. If that doesn't work, re-save the intent in Dialogflow, then try steps in #1
3. If that doesn't work, re-deploy `functions`, then try steps in #1

Also, does this work on a physical phone (is it just Simulator that's misbehaving)?

Would have made this a comment since it isn't *totally* an answer but I don't have enough reputation yet  so answer it is

Comment: I will give this a go this evening, I'm not certain if it's just the simulator misbehaving - I'll have to confirm that as well. I did try a quick test on my phone earlier today and the app crashed - but I'm not certain what that error was.

Comment: `Re-select the DRAFT version of your action in Simulator (click on "CHANGE VERSION" and re-select "VERSION - Draft"),` - This did it for me, what is the explanation behind this. is the system caching an old Draft?